# Change QTabWidget Active Tab From Other Class

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to mimic the tab button behaviour with buttons from another class.

So that when I click the Orders or History button the corresponding tab is selected.

ATM the code I have seems to work in so far as updating the currentIndex attribute as it prints correctly (0 for Orders and 1 for History).

However this change does not seem to reflect in the window, am I right in thinking this is an 'update widget' problem? If so how do I 'refresh' it?
If not am I missing some fundamental concept?

I've slimmed the code as much as I could...

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

Application = QApplication(sys.argv)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Layout #
        Layout = QVBoxLayout()
        Layout.addLayout(LayoutTabButtons())
        Layout.addWidget(Tabs())
        self.setLayout(Layout)
        self.show()
        
class Tabs(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Children #
        self.addTab(QLabel('This Is The Orders Page'),'Orders')
        self.addTab(QLabel('This Is The History Page'),'History')

        # Connections #
        InstanceButtonOrders = ButtonOrders(self)
        InstanceButtonHistory = ButtonHistory(self)

    def ChangeIndex(self, Input):
        self.setCurrentIndex(Input)
        print(self.currentIndex()) # <--- Prints Correctly

class LayoutTabButtons(QHBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__() 

        # Children #
        self.addWidget(ButtonOrders(Tabs()))
        self.addWidget(ButtonHistory(Tabs()))

class ButtonOrders(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, Tabs): 
        super().__init__()  

        # Content #
        self.setText('Orders') 

        # Connections #
        self.clicked.connect(lambda: self.SetIndex(Tabs)) 

    def SetIndex(self,Tabs):
        Tabs.ChangeIndex(0)

class ButtonHistory(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, Tabs): 
        super().__init__() 

        # Content #
        self.setText('History')

        # Connections #
        self.clicked.connect(lambda: self.SetIndex(Tabs)) 

    def SetIndex(self,Tabs):
        Tabs.ChangeIndex(1)

InstanceWindow = Window()

sys.exit(Application.exec_())
```

As an aside my 1st instinct was to go through the PyQt5 module files in order to get a clue as to how the default behaviour is done, but as Qt is written in C++ that wasn't an option here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating 3 instances of `Tabs`, therefore each `clicked()` signal is connected to its "own" instance of Tabs.

The `Window` constructor creates one of them directly and the other two are created by `LayoutTabButtons`

```
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Layout #
        Layout = QVBoxLayout()
        Layout.addLayout(LayoutTabButtons()) # <-- 2 here
        Layout.addWidget(Tabs()) # <-- 1 here
        self.setLayout(Layout)
        self.show()
```

The other two, which are never shown, because they're just connected to one button and nothing else.

```
class LayoutTabButtons(QHBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__() 

        # Children #
        self.addWidget(ButtonOrders(Tabs()))  # <-- Here
        self.addWidget(ButtonHistory(Tabs())) # <-- Here
```

To make your code work you have to keep an instance of `Tabs` inside the parent `Window` and pass it to the children.

```
Application = QApplication(sys.argv)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tabs = Tabs() # <-- The local instance!
        # Layout #
        Layout = QVBoxLayout()
        Layout.addLayout(LayoutTabButtons(self.tabs)) # <-- Passed to the children
        Layout.addWidget(self.tabs) # <-- Added to the layout
        self.setLayout(Layout)
        self.show()

class Tabs(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Children #
        self.addTab(QLabel('This Is The Orders Page'),'Orders')
        self.addTab(QLabel('This Is The History Page'),'History')

        # Connections #
        # Now the class has local instances of the buttons
        self.InstanceButtonOrders = ButtonOrders(self)   # <-- local instance
        self.InstanceButtonHistory = ButtonHistory(self) # <-- local instance

    def ChangeIndex(self, Input):
        self.setCurrentIndex(Input)
        print(self.currentIndex()) # <-- Prints Correctly

class LayoutTabButtons(QHBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, tabs):
        super().__init__()

        # Children #
        # Now the layout gets the buttons in Tabs
        self.addWidget(tabs.InstanceButtonOrders)
        self.addWidget(tabs.InstanceButtonHistory)

class ButtonOrders(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, tabs):
        super().__init__()

        self.tabs = tabs # <-- These are the tabs in Window
        # Content #
        self.setText('Orders')

        # Connections #
        self.clicked.connect(self.SetIndex) # <-- The lambda was superfluos

    def SetIndex(self):
        self.tabs.ChangeIndex(0)

class ButtonHistory(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, tabs):
        super().__init__()

        self.tabs = tabs # These are the tabs in Window
        # Content #
        self.setText('History')

        # Connections #
        self.clicked.connect(self.SetIndex) # <-- The lambda was superfluos

    def SetIndex(self):
        self.tabs.ChangeIndex(1)

InstanceWindow = Window()

sys.exit(Application.exec_())
```

However, while with a simple fix your code works, **it has serious design issues.**
The buttons should **not** depend on the tabs, they shouldn't even *know* about them.
In fact you should use plain QPushButtons and the only object aware of them should be the instance of Tabs, that would handle the interaction between tabs and buttons.

---

Here's a little refactoring that tries to stay close as possible to the OP idea while avoiding unnecessary classes

```
Application = QApplication(sys.argv)

class TabWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tabs = Tabs()
        # Layout #
        Layout = QVBoxLayout()
        Layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        self.setLayout(Layout)
        self.show()

    def AddTab(self, Widget, Name, Button=None):
        self.tabs.AddTab(Widget, Name, Button)

class Tabs(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.buttons = []
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()

        # Buttons bar layout #
        self.barLayout = QHBoxLayout()

        # Window layout #
        Layout = QVBoxLayout()
        Layout.addLayout(self.barLayout)
        Layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        self.setLayout(Layout)

    # Sets up a new tab with its button
    # and connects the click to ChangeIndex()
    def AddTab(self, Widget, Name, Button=None):
        self.tabs.addTab(Widget, Name)

        # Uses QPushButton by default, but can be replaced
        # by providing any instance of QAbstractButton
        if Button is None:
            Button = QPushButton(Name)
        index = len(self.buttons)
        Button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ChangeIndex(index))

        self.buttons.append(Button)
        self.barLayout.addWidget(Button)

    def ChangeIndex(self, Input):
        self.tabs.setCurrentIndex(Input)
        print(self.tabs.currentIndex()) # <-- Prints Correctly

InstanceWindow = TabWindow()
# Tabs #
InstanceWindow.AddTab(QLabel('This Is The Orders Page'), 'Orders')
InstanceWindow.AddTab(QLabel('This Is The History Page'), 'History')

sys.exit(Application.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I know it's a lot to ask but could you give me an example of a 'best practice' version of this code, I've a lot more gui to write and I'd hate for it to have major design flaws.

Comment: @MegaDutcher You're welcome! I'll add a "reduced" version of this script that avoids the unnecessary Buttons classes, but you should take a look at eyllanesc's answer for a well structured refactoring. He already gave you a really good implementation, even though he has not explained it much :)

Comment: Perhaps I should have been a bit more clear about the buttons, I want all of them to be their own class. In this case (and future cases) they are predetermined and thus have no need to be programmatically added...for this specific case they are part of a very complex menubar, and the default QTabWidget header buttons will be hidden. the classes and the way the layouts work in my example need to remain intact, I gutted this code in order to focus on the problem at hand but the overall structure should not be changed...rather only the 'connection'.

Comment: This is also the reason eyllanesc's example doesn't really work for me as it changes too many structural things about the example, however you pointed out that the way I'm implementing the connection is a fundamentally bad way to go about it...so if there is a way to 'fix' the connection without affecting the order of the base classes, then that's what I'm looking for...apologies I should have included the prerequisite to keep the general structure intact in the original question (which yours did).

Comment: @MegaDutcher How about that? By the way, why don't you use a `QStackedWidget` instead of a `QTabWidget`?

Comment: Again thanks a bunch! You've both given me enough to chew on for a while, and I'm currently working on an implementation that uses QStackedWidget (Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't even know it existed)...once I've sorted it all out I'll post the revised version of my original code in case others run into the same wall.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you are thinking that doing "X()" will always create the same class object and that is false (unless you have implemented a singleton). In addition, the idea is to create objects that have a limited scope and that share information through signals as if it were a black box where there are only inputs and outputs and what is inside does not matter. Considering the above, a possible solution is:

```py
from enum import IntEnum
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QLabel,
    QPushButton,
    QTabWidget,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)


class Page(IntEnum):
    OrderPage = 0
    HistoryPage = 1


class Button(QPushButton):
    pageChanged = pyqtSignal(Page)

    def __init__(self, text, page, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._page = page

        self.setText(text)
        self.clicked.connect(self.handle_clicked)

    @property
    def page(self):
        return self._page

    def handle_clicked(self):
        self.pageChanged.emit(self.page)


class ButtonsContainer(QWidget):
    pageChanged = pyqtSignal(Page)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        lay = QHBoxLayout(self)

    def add_button(self, text, page):
        button = Button(text, page)
        button.pageChanged.connect(self.pageChanged)
        self.layout().addWidget(button)


class Tabs(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.addTab(QLabel("This Is The Orders Page"), "Orders")
        self.addTab(QLabel("This Is The History Page"), "History")

    def change_page(self, page):
        self.setCurrentIndex(page)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        button_container = ButtonsContainer()
        button_container.add_button("Orders", Page.OrderPage)
        button_container.add_button("History", Page.HistoryPage)

        tabs = Tabs()

        button_container.pageChanged.connect(tabs.change_page)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(button_container)
        layout.addWidget(tabs)


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = Window()
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

For example, in my previous code, each button is associated with each page, and when it is clicked, it sends the page that is received by the ButtonsContainer class, and the latter transmits it to the QTabWidget. So you could add more buttons for more pages without changing anything.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately this changes too much of the structure of the example code, I need the classes and layouts to stay the same...the code I provided is a gutted version and by no means represents the 'final' product. For instance the buttons are part of a much more complex menubar and need to remain as separate classes for a bunch of other stuff (not included) to keep working, the same goes for the layouts...new classes are fine but the ones present are needed and should not be removed...I should probably have included that in the original question, apologies.

Comment: @MegaDutcher 1) I only respond with the information that the OP provides, I do not claim anything else. 2) Restructure the code because in my opinion you have a bad design, my code is readable and scalable, for example I could add more pages and buttons without adding much code. 3) My answer is not only intended to help the OP but the community so if the OP restricts me to follow their bad practices then I will not follow those restrictions, and I will publish a restructured code like what I have done.